# How to get a data after react select using axios and ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, react-select

I am newbie on ReactJS, I want to get a Price value just after the select of the Product name by react select and display it.

My method :

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
     PrixV: ""

     }
        PrixDisplay(selectprdt) {
            return axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
             if (response && response.data) {
                this.setState({
                  PrixV: response.data
                });
              }
console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
            });
          }
```

I try to read this value by :

```
<p>{this.state.PrixV} </p>
```

When I run it, nothing is displayd on the Price column and after I select the product name, I get :

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {PrixV}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at AjouterFacture.js:383)
```

And the console returns :

```
[{…}]0: {PrixV: "250.000"}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I read and display it ?

Comment: Instead of returning `response.data` you should store it in state and reference that. That way you can check if it exists, if not display an empty string and if so display your data

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak How to make that please ?

Comment: it will return promise and you can use promise(object) inside interpolation operator {{}}, thats the root cause .

Comment: well instead of saying `return response.data` you'll want to say `this.setState({ yourData: response.data})` and instead of saying ` <p>{this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)}</p>` you'll want to do something like `<p>{this.state.yourData}</p>`

Comment: when working with ReactJS and promises this is always how you'll want to handle retrieving and storing your data

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I get `Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {PrixV}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Can you take at look please ? I edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the map, try to change the code like this :

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
     Prix: []};
    render() {
    let {
          Prix
        } = this.state.Prix;
    return (
     <td>
 {  this.state.Prix.map((pr, k) => 
      <p key={k} >{pr.PrixV} </p>
                       )} 
                         </td>
    );}
    PrixDisplay(selectprdt) {
        return axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
         if (response && response.data) {
            this.setState({
              Prix: response.data
            });
          }

        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);

        });
      }
```

I hope that's will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
                mydata: ''
};

productNameSelected(selectprdt) {//not sure from where you will get selectprdt variable , but something like this will work
    axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
        if (response && response.data) {
          this.setState( {mydata : response.data});
      }
      console.log(response.data)
      })
  }

<p>{this.state.mydata} </p> //my data should not be a object , so you need to make string if you wnat to directly use it here
```

Edit

I can see you are able to get the response , but react still gives error:-
change the paragrah code to

```
<p>{this.state.PrixV[0].PrixV} </p>
```

Or The good way will be to set the data properly so 
let paragrah be same

```
<p>{this.state.PrixV} </p>

PrixDisplay(selectprdt) {
    return axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
        if (response && response.data && response.data[0]) {
            this.setState({
            PrixV: response.data[0].PrixV
            });
        }
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

You are getting the error because currently you are getting PrixV as an array(object) not a primitive data type.
Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: I want to get the value of Price after I select the product name with react select ! I

Comment: so on change of the select you are going to call this function right ?

Comment: updated the code , just call productNameSelected on change of product name

Comment: This my onChange of the select :  `handleselectprdtChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {
      selectprdt: value }); this.setState({rowData: rowDataCopy, }); }`   I just I put the method of Price after the render.

Comment: Sorry @Atul, it get [] the value of Price

Comment: can you pls share the whole code , the price selection dropdown and how you are passing the price?
wont be able to help without that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178223/discussion-between-atul-and-melissa).

Comment: @Melissa i have edited my Answer based on you new inputs, try the edited soln now.